# How to create authorized view in Google bigquery for multiple dynamic tables?

Tags: google-bigquery

I am looking to implement row level security in GCP, though the authorized view is a way to handle this, my use case has multiple tables created dynamically. How can we implement access control here, Do we need to have a separate view created for each table and saved in a different data set?

Comment: it is not clear what exactly your use-case is! please give us more details

Comment: In my use case , I have more than 1000 tables in a dataset which are created dynamically through a workflow. I want to implement row level security for a user who should be able to view data relevant to his permissions or say some subset of data. How do I implement this?

Answer (score 0):

Following the [procedure of creating authorize views](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/share-access-views), you could:

1. Create your source dataset (where your dynamic tables would reside).
2. Create one dataset (to store views) for every group of users with the same permissions, e.g. one dataset for developers, other for analysts, other for testers, etc.
3. Assign a project-level Cloud IAM role to your users (for them to be able to create BigQuery query jobs).
4. Assign to each user access controls to the dataset which will contain the views and correspond to their group (from step 2).
5. Dynamically create a table.
6. Dynamically create a view for each dataset (from step 2) querying the information that group should have access to (Please note you cannot create the views upfront, since the reference tables should exist).
7. Dynamically authorize the views.

For steps 3 and 4, alternatively, you can assign your users to [Google Groups](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/overview#google_group) (you'll have one dataset per group).

Also be mindful of [these limits](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/quotas#view_limits).